# d3js v4 - J hoop chart - long stem with a curved arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a d3 application - which features a hooped chart. I have a version which is a radial 360 type of chart - but I am unsure how you'd configure the path to arc in this fashion.

[image]

//old js fiddle of a crescent chart
http://jsfiddle.net/2wfktc3g/

```js
var $this = $('.crescentchart');

var data = [{
    label: 'Fudge Brownie',
    value: 5,
  },
  {
    label: 'Cherry Vanilla',
    value: 60,
  },
  {
    label: 'Pistachio',
    value: 5,
  },
  {
    label: 'Caramel',
    value: 10,
  }
];

var oldData = "";

var width = $this.data('width'),
  height = $this.data('height'),
  radius = $this.data('r'),
  thickness = $this.data("thickness"),
  spacing = $this.data("spacing");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#bc658d", "#82c4c3", "#f9d89c", "#f5a7a7"]);

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'crescentchart')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments');

var data = setData(data, radius);

//append previous value to it.
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  if (oldData[index] != undefined) {
    data[index]["previousEndAngle"] = oldData[index].endAngle;
  } else {
    data[index]["previousEndAngle"] = 0;
  }
});

var arcpaths = segments.selectAll("path")
  .data(data);

arcpaths.enter().append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .transition()
  .ease(d3.easeElastic)
  .duration(750)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    return arcTween(d, thickness, radius);
  });

arcpaths.transition()
  .ease(d3.easeElastic)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .duration(750)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    return arcTween(d, thickness, radius);
  });

arcpaths.exit().transition()
  .ease(d3.easeBounce)
  .duration(750)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    return arcTween(d, thickness, radius);
  })
  .remove();

function arcTween(b, thickness, ir) {
  var prev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
  prev.endAngle = b.previousEndAngle;
  var i = d3.interpolate(prev, b);

  return function(t) {
    return getArc(thickness, ir)(i(t));
  };
}

function getRadiusRing(ir, i) {
  return ir - (i * (thickness + spacing));
}

function getArc(thickness, ir) {
  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(function(d) {
      return getRadiusRing(ir, d.index);
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
      return getRadiusRing(ir + thickness, d.index);
    })
    .startAngle(function(d, i) {
      return d.startAngle;
    })
    .endAngle(function(d, i) {
      return d.endAngle;
    });
  return arc;
}

function setData(data, r) {
  var diameter = (2 * Math.PI) * r;

  var segmentValueSum = 0;
  $.each(data, function(ri, va) {
    segmentValueSum += va.value;
  });

  $.each(data, function(ri, va) {
    var segmentValue = va.value;

    var fraction = segmentValue / segmentValueSum;

    var arcBatchLength = fraction * (2 * Math.PI);
    var arcPartition = arcBatchLength;
    var startAngle = Math.PI;
    var endAngle = startAngle + arcPartition;

    data[ri]["startAngle"] = startAngle;
    data[ri]["endAngle"] = endAngle;
    data[ri]["index"] = ri;
  });

  return data;
}


//legend
var legendsvgw = 150;
var legendsvgh = 100;

var ringRadius = 5;
var vertical = 20;

var legendsvg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", legendsvgw)
  .attr("height", legendsvgh)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'legendsvg')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 10 + "," + 10 + ")");

var legend = legendsvg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");


var labels = legend.selectAll("text.labels")
  .data(data);

labels.enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "labels")
  .attr("dx", 15)
  .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
    return (vertical * i) + ringRadius * 2;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return "start";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  });

labels.exit().remove();


var ring = legend.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data);

ring.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return (vertical * i) + ringRadius;
  })
  .attr("r", ringRadius)
  .attr("width", ringRadius * 2)
  .attr("height", ringRadius * 2)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  });

ring.exit().remove();
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<h1>CrescentChart I</h1>
<div class="crescentchart" data-width="300" data-height="300" data-r="90" data-thickness="6" data-spacing="10" />
```

Comment: Please be more explicit in what you want, right now there's no question. Do you want the bars to curve upwards like in the example or do you want a 3d version of what you have now?

Comment: So I have a radial chart - but I am unsure on how to turn it into a J shape

Comment: Just a 2D version of it

Comment: Where should the 0 value lie? Should the bar be completely invisible or should it just be a regular bar chart with a curly appendix? Should it be possible for a bar to end before the narrow part?

Comment: the bar be completely invisible

Comment: I see it as a version of the chart I already got -- but instead of drawing a perfect circle - it draws a J shape - I do have a line drawing thing

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep it in line with your current implementation, I'd consider two different cases. One where `d.fraction <= 0.25`, so the arc part is the only thing required to draw the bar. In that case, just use the arc. The other, when `d.fraction > 0.25`, you can draw yourself, because you can assume already that the arc goes exactly from 180 to 270 degrees, and all you need it to draw the bar on top before closing it. I used [`d3.path()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-path) extensively for this example, I recommend you keep it next to you when reading the code.

```js
var $this = $('.crescentchart');

var data = [{
    label: 'Fudge Brownie',
    value: 45,
  },
  {
    label: 'Cherry Vanilla',
    value: 60,
  },
  {
    label: 'Pistachio',
    value: 5,
  },
  {
    label: 'Caramel',
    value: 10,
  }
];

var oldData = "";

var width = $this.data('width'),
  height = $this.data('height'),
  radius = $this.data('r'),
  thickness = $this.data("thickness"),
  spacing = $this.data("spacing");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#bc658d", "#82c4c3", "#f9d89c", "#f5a7a7"]);

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'crescentchart')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments');

var data = setData(data, radius);

//append previous value to it.
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  if (oldData[index] != undefined) {
    data[index]["previousFraction"] = oldData[index].fraction;
  } else {
    data[index]["previousFraction"] = 0;
  }
});

var arcpaths = segments.selectAll("path")
  .data(data);

arcpaths.enter().append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .transition()
  .ease(d3.easeElastic)
  .duration(3000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    return arcTween(d, thickness, radius);
  });

arcpaths.transition()
  .ease(d3.easeElastic)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .duration(3000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    return arcTween(d, thickness, radius);
  });

arcpaths.exit().transition()
  .ease(d3.easeBounce)
  .duration(3000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    return arcTween(d, thickness, radius);
  })
  .remove();

function arcTween(b, thickness, ir) {
  var prev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
  prev.endAngle = b.previousEndAngle;
  prev.fraction = b.previousFraction;
  var i = d3.interpolate(prev, b);
  const arc = getArc(thickness, ir);

  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function getRadiusRing(ir, i) {
  return ir - (i * (thickness + spacing));
}

// The portion of the fraction that is drawn as an arc,
// instead of as a straight part
const arcPortion = 3 / 8;

function getArc(thickness, ir) {
  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(function(d) {
      return getRadiusRing(ir, d.index);
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
      return getRadiusRing(ir + thickness, d.index);
    })
    .startAngle(- arcPortion * 2 * Math.PI)
    .endAngle(function(d, i) {
      return -(d.fraction + arcPortion) * 2 * Math.PI;
    });
  
  // This function is only called when endAngle is greater than
  // 3 * Math.PI, otherwise we simply draw an arc, because it makes
  // no difference.
  function jShape(d, i) {
    const context = d3.path();
    const innerRadius = getRadiusRing(ir, d.index);
    const outerRadius = getRadiusRing(ir + thickness, d.index);
    const startAngle = -arcPortion * 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;
    const endAngle = 0;

    // Start at the correct position on the inside
    context.moveTo(
      innerRadius * Math.cos(startAngle),
      innerRadius * Math.sin(startAngle)
    );
    
    context.arc(0, 0, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
    
    // Now draw the straight part
    const fullLength = innerRadius * 2 * Math.PI;
    
    // The first 0.25 corresponds to the curved part drawn earlier.
    const straightLength = (d.fraction - arcPortion) * fullLength
    context.lineTo(
      innerRadius * Math.cos(endAngle),
      innerRadius * Math.sin(endAngle) - straightLength
    );

    // Move to the outside
    context.lineTo(
      outerRadius * Math.cos(endAngle),
      innerRadius * Math.sin(endAngle) - straightLength
    );
    
    context.lineTo(
      outerRadius * Math.cos(endAngle),
      outerRadius * Math.sin(endAngle)
    );

    // And curve back
    context.arc(0, 0, outerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, false);
    context.closePath();

    return context + "";
  }
  
  return function(d, i) {
    return d.fraction <= arcPortion ? arc(d, i) : jShape(d, i);
  }
}

function setData(data, r) {
  var segmentValueSum = 0;
  $.each(data, function(ri, va) {
    segmentValueSum += va.value;
  });

  $.each(data, function(ri, va) {
    var segmentValue = va.value;
    var fraction = segmentValue / segmentValueSum;

    data[ri]["index"] = ri;
    data[ri]["fraction"] = fraction;
  });

  return data;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<h1>CrescentChart I</h1>
<div class="crescentchart" data-width="300" data-height="300" data-r="90" data-thickness="6" data-spacing="10" />
```

Comment: how do you mirror it the other way so its more like a J

Comment: where did you get the maths to adjust the path like that? That's pretty impressive

Comment: You can mirror it by just flipping the `x` negative or positive everywhere, or by using `transform: scale(-1, 1);` on the paths. For adjusting the paths, I just looked at the source code for `arc()`. It's not so complex if you remove all the edge case logic (like rounded corners) and know that the path starts at PI/2 and ends at PI

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yeLb5u9m/1/ - put it n a Jsfiddle

Comment: no - I mean it grows from the right to the left - to form a J

Comment: [It does that](https://jsfiddle.net/w950hzdq/) if you add `.attr("transform", "scale(-1, 1)")` to the paths

Comment: yeah - but its still not what I meant -- I mean - grow from the right of the J tip --  to the point of the curve -- so not really meaning just flip

Comment: you have all of the attempts I've made to date -- the closest chart I had was this crescent chart concept -- but it may require more of a line path drawing concept -- but then that may take it out of the pie/chart type framework here

Comment: I've added a variable `arcPortion`. It denotes how much of the total length of the bar should be in the arc (vs the straight part). 1/4 is the old situation, 1 gives a circle. The current setting at 3/8 gives you your candy cane shape

Comment: interesting solution - I've put it into a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5vwqzd6L/1/